# AngularJS and Vaadin in the same application

Tags: angularjs, vaadin, vaadin7

Has anyone used both AngularJS and Vaadin within the same application? For instance, AngularJS pages that have no Vaadin code whatsoever. This is an unusual situation, I know, but just curious. I'm wondering about the security implications in particular.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe try to embed Vaadin into Angular through a div or iframe (both approaches are available and described in the book of vaadin):

[Embedding Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.embedding.html)

or (and haven't tried this) you can probably use a custom layout in vaadin (HTML view) with an angularjs app in it:

[Custom Layouts](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html#figure.layout.customlayout)

Answer (score 1):

If the pages (URL's) are different, then you can just use the correct mappings in your servlet engine.

If you need a interation on page level, then you will have to either embed vaadin in angular or vice versa.

How you can embed vaadin in other html pages is [described in the book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.embedding.html).
I don't know of a way to integrate angular in Vaadin, but this does not mean that none exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Vaadin add-on available (that I did help writing) that allows embedding AngularJS into Vaadin - i.e. have a Vaadin control whose contents are implemented as AngularJS. All communication follows Vaadin's principles - so there should not be significant differences in terms of security, behavior, etc.

Hope it's helpful 4u - here's the link: https://vaadin.com/addon/vaangular